# Problem making MinGW-64-compiled program self-contained in Windows XP

Tags: c++, mingw, 64-bit, static-libraries, windows-xp-sp2

I'm trying to migrate the MinGW compiler suite from 32 bits to 64.  My application has run under 32-bit MinGW for several years.  I installed MinGW-w64 in Late November.  The program versions are
C:\wba\sd>gcc --version
gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
C:\wba\sd>ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.30

My program has consisted of a small console app and small Windows app, with a large dll that they link to.  This stuff has all worked for several years on my Windows XP Service Pack 3 laptop.

I have used static linking to the various system services, because of problems I've had in the past.  The relevant makefile stuff is

```
CC = g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

libsdlib.a: sdlib.dll sdmain.o

sdlib.dll: sdmain.o
$(CC) -shared -o sdlib.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libsdlib.a sdmain.o
strip sdlib.dll

sdtty.exe: libsdlib.a sdlib.dll sdui-tty.o
$(CC) -mconsole -o $@ sdui-tty.o -L. -lsdlib
strip sdtty.exe
```

But the program now fails if it doesn't have access to libwinpthread-1.dll
When I'm set up for compilation, that's in the path.  Specifically, it's in
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll
But it isn't on the customers' computers.  I also have
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libpthread.a
and
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libpthread.dll.a
My attempts to produce the right incantation to get this statically liked into my program have been unsuccessful.
I'm a bit rusty on all this.  Can anyone help?

Comment: You might need a -static-winpthread. I do use this compiler but without libgcc or libstdc++.

Answer (score 0):

Also add the `-static` to link with static libraries.